# norm equivalent and isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two Hilbert spaces, $T:H_1\longrightarrow H_2$ be an one to one, onto linear map, and  there exist constant $C_1, C_2>0$ such that  $C_1\lVert u\rVert _1\leq\lVert Tu\rVert_2\leq C_2\lVert u\rVert_1$. Then is it possible to construct an onto isometry from $H_1$ to $H_2$ using $T?$

Comment: What do you mean construct?  Isn't T given?

Comment: Yes $T$ is given, but it may not be isometry, But I am looking for an sometry.

Comment: @Aweygan: $ T $ is necessarily injective. If $ u \in H_{1} $ and $ T(u) = 0_{H_{2}} $, then $ \| T(u) \|_{2} = 0 $. By the given inequality, $ C_{1} \| u \|_{1} = 0 $, so $ u = 0_{H_{1}} $.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) and take

$$ U = T (\sqrt{T^{*}T})^{-1}. $$

Comment: +1, thanks ,then the constants $C_1,C_2$ are immaterial.

Answer (score 0):

**Strengthening**

Given Hilbert spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Suppose *bounded* operator:
$$T\in\mathcal{B}(X,Y):\quad\mathcal{N}T=\{0\}\quad\overline{\mathcal{R}T}=Y$$

Regard modulus operator:
$$|T|:X\to X:\quad|T|:=\sqrt{T^*T}\implies|T|^2=T^*T$$

Remind square root lemma:
\begin{gather}\||T|x\|^2=\langle|T|x,|T|x\rangle=\langle|T|^2x,x\rangle\\
=\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=\|Tx\|^2\end{gather}

Deduce range and kernel:
$$\mathcal{R}|T|^\perp=\mathcal{N}|T|^*=\mathcal{N}|T|=\mathcal{N}T=\{0\}$$

Construct *unitary* operator:
$$U:X\leftrightarrow Y:\quad U:=\overline{T|T|^{-1}}\implies U^*=U=U^{-1}$$

Concluding unitary equivalence $X\cong Y$.

*(Note how the original operator needn't*
*be boundedly invertible nor have closed range!)*